# Sort table with unknown number of headers using jQuery Table Sort, then only sort on 2 headers

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

### The Scenario

I have a table on a web page that is dynamically generated using JSP. The number of columns/headers is variable (could be 6 or up to 40+). I'm using [jQuery Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html) to sort the table. The table should only sort on header elements 5 and 6 for the moment.

### The Question

Using Tablesorter allows you to [set certain header elements to false](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html), disabling them from the sort options. Since the number of headers is variable I need a way of inverting the options so that I can set the sorter option to true and the rest are disabled by default. Either that, or I need a way to get the total number of header elements and run through a loop to set them to false.

The syntax is a little tricky for me as I'm not sure how to loop through the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $("table").tablesorter({ 
            headers: { 
                0: { 
                    sorter: false 
                }, 
                1: { 
                    sorter: false 
                } 
                .
                .
                .
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

**So the only two I want to sort on in this example are *"Primary Disease" and "Risk Index"*.**

### The Code

Another small problem is that I have a row that needs to appear above the table header. It's basically a higher level of heading for the table information. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thepriebe/UZsFz/) with my code.

#### CSS

```css
th.headerSortUp { 
    background-image: url(../img/small_asc.gif); 
    background-color: #3399FF; 
}
th.headerSortDown { 
    background-image: url(../img/small_desc.gif); 
    background-color: #3399FF; 
}
th.header { 
    background-image: url(../img/small.gif);     
    cursor: pointer; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center left; 
    padding-left: 20px; 
    border-right: 1px solid #dad9c7; 
    margin-left: -1px; 
}
```

#### jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            2: { 
                sorter: true
            }, 
            3: { 
                sorter: true
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

#### HTML

```html
    <table border="3" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" valign="top" id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="stopGapTH" colspan="4">
            Patient List - all
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapTH" colspan="99">
            Clinical Adherence Information
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr height="30">
          <th width="10%" align="middle">
            Patient Name
          </th>
          <th width="5%" align="middle">
            DOB
          </th>
          <th width="5%" align="middle">
            Primary Disease
          </th>
          <th width="5%" align="middle">
            Risk Index
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Asthma</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Bipolar Disorder</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Chronic Kidney Disease</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Coronary Artery Disease</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Depression</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Diabetes</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Dyslipidemia</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Heart Failure</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Hypertension</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Peripheral Vascular Disease</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Schizophrenia</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Seizure Disorder</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Transient Ischemic Attack</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Preventive Care</a>
          </th>
          <th class="stopGapConditionHeader" align="middle">
            <a href="">Wellness</a>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="stopGapRow">
          <td>
            Louis Armstrong
          </td>
          <td>
            02/01/1987
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            80%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            42%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            90%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            16%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition notApplicable">
            N/A
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            40%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="stopGapRow">
          <td>
            Bob Barker
          </td>
          <td>
            10/10/1951
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            80%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            75%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            77%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            33%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="stopGapRow">
          <td>
            David Brinkley
          </td>
          <td>
            10/10/1951
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            80%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            16%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            70%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            42%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            40%
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="stopGapRow">
          <td>
            Tom Brokaw
          </td>
          <td>
            10/10/1954
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            40%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            85%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            70%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            57%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition notApplicable">
            N/A
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            71%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            40%
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="stopGapRow">
          <td>
            Cad2 Sandy
          </td>
          <td>
            01/01/1955
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            75%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            62%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            63%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            60%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition notApplicable">
            N/A
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            60%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="stopGapRow">
          <td>
            Cad3 Sandy
          </td>
          <td>
            01/01/1955
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            60%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            75%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            63%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            57%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="stopGapRow">
          <td>
            Cad4 Sandy
          </td>
          <td>
            01/01/1955
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            33%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            37%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            63%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition notApplicable">
            N/A
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            80%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            83%
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="stopGapRow">
          <td>
            Cad5 Sandy
          </td>
          <td>
            01/01/1955
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            40%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            33%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            75%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            63%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            85%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            14%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="stopGapRow">
          <td>
            Alex Trebek
          </td>
          <td>
            10/10/1951
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            33%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            16%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            75%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            63%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            33%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            80%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            40%
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="stopGapRow">
          <td>
            Chucka Woolerya
          </td>
          <td>
            10/15/1951
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td>
            NA
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            83%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            66%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            42%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            54%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            71%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition green">
            100%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition red">
            0%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
          <td class="stopGapCondition yellow">
            50%
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**EDIT: So the header "Patient List - All" and "Clinical Adherence Information" are headers 0 and 1. So the headers "Primary Disease" and "Risk Level" are actually 5 and 6.**

**EDIT2: Needs to work with IE8+.**

Comment: position of the "Primary Disease" and "Risk Index" always same or have to find them first?

Comment: Great question. Should always be in position 2 and 3. The patient list won't change unless there's a major code change. Thanks!

Comment: Actually need a better definition of rules you want...is still a bit loose

Comment: I guess this requires even more clarification because there are two headers above the main list of headers. I'll make an edit in the question.

Comment: looks like @fudgey has what you need anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it would be easier if you tried out my fork of [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html) on github, which allows you to [apply class names to the header](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html) to disable the sort. Then all you need to do is something like this:

```
$('table thead th')
  .addClass('sorter-false')
  .filter(':eq(2), :eq(3)').removeClass('sorter-false');
```

---

Ok, try this method ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/UZsFz/9/)):

```
var headers = {},
    $table = $('#myTable'), i,
    l = $table.find('thead th').length,

    // columns 0 and 1 are the top row "Patient List - all"
    // and "Clinical Adherence Information"
    sortcolumns = [2, 3, 4, 5];

// build headers object; based on sortcolumn selections
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if ($.inArray(i, sortcolumns) < 0) {
        headers[i] = {
            sorter: false
        }
    }
}
$table.tablesorter({
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    headers: headers // headers object built above
});
```

Comment: No offense to your skills or anything, but I'd prefer to not use a forked version of the code. This is for a major corporation that needs to rely on this code for a long time.

Comment: Oops, sorry `indexOf()` doesn't exist in IE8... so instead use jQuery's [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) like this: `$.inArray(i, sortcolumns) < 0`. I'll update the code & demo above.